# Windows 10 memory problems

Tags: windows-10, memory

Now I don't want to label it "memory leak" per se, because usually in topics with that name it all comes down to old drivers and non-paged pool. And I think I've already passed that point by following most of those advices.

My situation is a bit different. Something is using a lot of memory and it isn't clearly shown in task manager. After a reboot the situation becomes better, then with time gradually the system takes up more and more RAM, even though nothing is really running, and no one is really doing anything with the computer.

Today is a good example: my wife left to work after me and forgot to shut down the PC. No biggie, of course. But when I come home, I see that half my memory is already gone, and that's approximately 7.3 GBs of RAM. I mean, where did it go, who or what used it all up?

It looks like this:

[image: Task Manager screenshot]

[image: Performance Tab Screenshot]

It all just doesn't add up to such high usage. I am definitely missing something here. When I was using Windows 8.1 this would never go up like this. I mean I had 8 GBs then, not even 16.

Comment: Have a look in the resource monitor, on the memory tab. It will give you more verbose data about what memory is used, such as shared memory. To get here click the "Open resource Monitor" in the performance tab of task manager.

Comment: I actually wanted to post that screen as well, I just did't have enough rep. The situation there is pretty similar. It doesn't add up to such huge amounts. 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/a0zSH.png

Comment: Look at Sysinternals Suite, it's a Microsoft set of apps.  ProcExp is Process Explorer and give a lot more detail about running processes.  Perhaps this will help you find the program hogging your RAM

Comment: Order by 'shareable' col. This exact thing happens to me, and its the shareable amount that is always high.

Comment: Ordered by shareable:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvg28.png

Comment: It’s interesting how there is more in-use memory than committed memory. These figures would usually be reversed. Please get Sysinternals RAMMap and provide a screenshot of its start view.

Comment: RAMMap: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iDm1T.png

Comment: Right, Mapped Files it is. Please change to the “File Summary” tab and order by “Active”. /edit: Oh yeah, and provide a screenshot of course. :)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gVSuM.png Wow, it seem like BitTorrent is to blame?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/78t9A.png this is what I see now without BitTorrent. Almost clean. That's a great remedy! Thanks! But I still would like to use :)

Comment: @dharlequin Keep in mind that memory that is "in use" is not permanently in use for its current purpose. If something else comes along that needs more RAM Windows will automatically shrink existing processes' working sets  to make room. Conversely, if there's plenty of RAM, Windows will allow things to grow. And you have plenty. In fact, even with your reported "problem" you have more "available" RAM than practically all PCs had until just a few years ago! Unless you're seeing performance problems (e.g. when you start up something new), don't worry about it.

Comment: I actually did see problems. Mainly with how chrome responded to my actions. And how Just Cause 3 and Rise of Tomb Raider performed with constant stuttering and freezes. All of these started to occur when I upgraded to Windows 10 before it went pay-to-upgrade. Just cause 3 was saying that I didn't have enough memory, and it was a nightmare. So I upgraded to 16 GBs, it became much better. But then after this fix here it ran perfectly, at least considering my dated gpu and cpu. So maybe I didn't have to upgrade and live with 8 GBs of RAM. But there were no such problems on Windows 8.1, never.

Comment: @dharlequin you should merge your investigative comments into your main question in order to help others with similar issues more easily locate the question.

Comment: Re "it wasn't this bad before", maybe you weren't torrenting as many files at the same time, or as fast, before. The number of active torrents at one time is, by the way. a limit you can place in most torrent clients. Maybe you should investigate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear µTorrent (also available as “BitTorrent”) uses memory mapped files to access on-disk data. It’s generally a highly efficient method.

Judging from various reports, µTorrent has a rather liberal policy on how long to keep file parts in-memory. There is an advanced switch, `diskio.flush_files`, that is supposed to make µTorrent close and reopen all file handles every minute. However, in several threads from 2015, users reported this switch has no effect.

µTorrent might have some settings that control memory usage.

Because memory usage doesn’t seem at critical levels on your system, you can just keep using your PC as is. If you ever do run into performance issues, it might be time to switch to another BitTorrent client that is more resource-friendly.